# Having live traffic with Google Traffic Tile on QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, quickmapservices

I have added a Google Traffic Tile from QuickMapServices on QGIS 3.16 and noticed that I don't know what the update period is, if it has one.

Is there any way to know how the updating works on this kind of tile so I can update it manually?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Bullet lists of questions will often result in closure for lack of focus. Questions here should also demonstrate an effort to research the topic. It's not clear who the provider is, or what their service metadata might indicate. Please [Edit] the Question to provide more information about the service you are using.

Comment: Mods, what exactly do you find unclear about this question? It seems perfectly clear to me.